# How to open public port 8888 in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, google-cloud-platform

I want to open a port on Google Cloud Platform. I have a virtual machine that is with OS Ubuntu vs 14. There is an Instagram server and a PostgreSQL database. 
I need to send data from a gps to a public IP on port 8888. How can I do it? It does not let me open a port, it is opened by default 80 and 22, but it does not let me open other ports, I've tried everything and I can not. Created the firewall rules and does not work.

Answer (score 4):

As you are having trouble adding a firewall rules, I'm going to suggest some firewall rules settings for testing purposes, which you may want to lock down with more stringent security settings once you have confirmed these settings work.

To open the firewall rule for port 8888 in Google Cloud Platform follow these steps.

1) Navigate to VPC Network > Firewall rules > Create firewall rule.

2) In the 'Create a firewall rule' page, select these settings:

- Name - choose a name for this firewall rule
- Network - select the name of the network your instance belongs to, most probably 'default' unless you've configured a custom network.
- Direction of traffic - 'Ingress'.
- Action on match - 'Allow'.
- Targets - 'All instances in the network'.
- Source filter - 'IP ranges'.
- Source IP ranges - '0.0.0.0/0'.
- Second source filter - 'None'.
- Specified protocols and ports - 'tcp:8888' or 'udp:8888' depending on whether the protocol you are using uses tcp or udp.

3) Hit 'Create'.

This will create a rule allowing traffic on port 8888 to all instances in your network from all IP address sources.

My advice would be to see if these settings work, and then once confirming this, lock down the settings by specifying a specific IP address or range of IP addresses in the 'Source IP ranges' text box, and adding a target tag to you instance and specifying 'Specified target tags' so the port is only open to the instance.

If this doesn't work, you may have the firewall rule turned on within the instance, which you would need to configure (or turn it off).

For more detailed information about setting firewall rules please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls).